# Bash script cd issues

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

Hi all I have some problems with my script. I've read that changing the current directory from within a script is a bit of an issue. Basically I am looking for a single php file with a project folder and any sub-folders in it. And I want to change the directory to where that folder is and perform a command for it. So far no luck.

```
function findPHP(){
declare -a FILES
FILES=$(find ./ -name \*.php)
for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do

DIR=`dirname file`
( cd $DIR && doSomethingInThisDir &(...))

done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As with other (related) question; what *is* happening?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to iterate over `FILES` as an array, but it only has one element. In order to make the result of your subshell into an array, you can:

```
FILES=($(find ./ -name \*.php))
```

Note that it splits file names on spaces, so even though you properly quote below, it won't help.  Alternatively, you could just let it split below (i.e. using your existing `FILES`) and use instead:

```
for file in $FILES
```

If you are using `bash 4`, you may want to have a look at recursive globbing... this would make it a bit easier:

```
for file in **/*.php
```

Note that you have to have the `globstar` shell option set, which you could enable with `shopt -s globstar`. This way is simpler and won't break on whitespace.

Also, you probably want `$file` here:

```
DIR=`dirname $file`
```

Or just use parameter expansion:

```
DIR=${file%/*}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use an array, or store the file list in anyway.  If your `find` supports `-execdir` (eg gnufind 4.2.27), then use it.  Otherwise, cd in a subshell as you have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
doSomethingInThisDir() ( cd $(dirname $1); ... )
export -f doSomethingInThisDir
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'doSomethingInThisDir {}' \;
```

I have defined the function using `()` instead of `{}`, but that is not necessary in this case.  Normally, using `()` causes the function to run in a subshell, but that happens here anyway because find runs a separate process for each file.